# Action Bar over the GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-actionbar

I'm using open GL in my app. I have also created an action bar in my activity which sets it's view as the surface view. However I'm not able to get the action bar. Is it behind my surface? I don't know. I'm just not able to get it. I have of course written the menu's xml file and also implemented onCreateOptionsMenu. Why am I not able to see the action bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem earlier. I had been using `setContentView(myGlSurfaceView);` in my MainActivity.
Ultimately, I found that it doesn't work to place an action bar on the GlSurfaceView. Instead, using a modification of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126353/opengl-view-inside-a-layout) post one can embed their GlSurfaceView in a linear layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.MyLinearLayout);
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyLinearLayout);
GLSurfaceView s = new GLSurfaceView(this);
s.setRenderer(myGLRenderer);
l.addView(s, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

You can now add an action bar to your app like normal. Note that the addView() parameters define how big the GlSurfaceView is. Read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#ViewGroup.LayoutParams%28int,%20int%29).

**EDIT**:
For future viewers, I have tested this and it works for toolbars (and really any views) as well!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nathan. It works perfectly.
But if you also want to show the options of the menu you need to add the next two code lines:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```