# How to properly place AdMob banner at top of GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, opengl-es-2.0

So I've been trying to place an AdMob Banner at the top of my game screen(which is rendered using openGL via an extended GLSurfaceView object). I'm using a RelativeLayout which I found was working for other people during my research, and it works for me when I'm aligning it to the bottom via`adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)` :

[image]

however when that is changed to `adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)` I run into problems:

[image]

It does place the ad at the top, but the entire bottom of the screen is white and my surfaceview is no longer visible. Why is it doing this? I've tried a bunch of different layouts and other suggestions I've found around but nothing seems to work.

I was able to get the ad to only take up a small portion of the screen using a ConstraintLayout and placing a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout which I added my GLSurfaceView to, but it wasn't displaying. It also seems as though the SurfaceView is there because I can hear the music transition and game being played when I do touch events.

Here's the code for what I'm currently doing:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //create our rendering surface
    mGLView = new GameSurfaceView(this, this);
    mGLView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

    //premium players don't get ads
    if(is_premium)
    {
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
    else
    {
        MobileAds.initialize(this, ad_app_id);

        //initialize interstitial ad
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ad_string_inter_test);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed()
            {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });

        //create our layout and add our openGL scene
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(mGLView);
        setContentView(layout);

        //initialize banner ad
        mBannerAd = new AdView(this);
        mBannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        mBannerAd.setAdUnitId(ad_string_banner_test);
        mBannerAd.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mBannerAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded()
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                //adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

                layout.addView(mBannerAd, adParams);
            }
        });


        //create ad request and begin loading
        AdRequest bannerRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_TEST_ID).build();
        mBannerAd.loadAd(bannerRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating your view on the run time? just create it in your XML, and the best responsive layout for this would be [constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), here is an example :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.ExpandableCategoriesMenu.ExpandableCategoriesMenu"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Soduku"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Ad mob  view"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Easy"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Medium"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="hard"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Exit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />
```

Comment: I'm using opengl to render my menu screen, and trying to place an ad at the top, sorry if I was unclear about that.

Comment: MAybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126353/opengl-view-inside-a-layout) can help

Comment: I attempted using a constraint layout in combination with my GLSurfaceView and am still having the same problem. For whatever reason the ad resizes to the bottom of the screen every time.